# How to reduce or increase the array elements but not change the shape of plot which array draws

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

array1: `[[1,2,3,4......,10000],[a1,a2,......,a10000]]`

array2: `[[1,2,3.....,1000000000],[b1,b2,.......b1000000000]]`

and want to resize them, so they can be samilar size like:

resized_array1:`[[1,3,19....9670,10000],[a1,a3,a19,........a9670,a10000]]`
resized_array2:`[[1,600,1929....1000000000],[b1,b600,b1929....b1000000000]]`

The plot of these two arrays are like pulse figure and I want to keep the peaks of two arrays.

So how can I do that in python?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the logic to reshape? can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @mozway Array2 data is collected by a 10000Hz instrument, and the data is like:`[0.112,0.112,.....350,500,200,0.112...600,0.123.....,0,0,0]` I want to keep all the peaks and reduce the number of elements

Comment: What happens if the number of peaks in one array is many more than the number of peaks in another array? E.g. `array1` has 1000 peak values and `array2` has 10000 peak values? Do you want some of the values from `array2` to be excluded, or do you want to include some non-peak values from `array1`?

Comment: Also, is the 1st sublist in each array (the `[1,2,3,4]`) just those numbers in order, i.e. the indices of the 2nd sublist but increased by 1? Or can those numbers be out-of-order?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the 1st sublist in each array (the `[1,2,3...,10000]`) is just an evenly spaced and ordered list of numbers, starting at 1 and spaced by 1, and that the 2nd sublist (`[a1,a2...a10000]` and `[b1,b2...b1000000000]`) are numerical and contain the peaks. I'm making the simple assumption that all nonzero values are peak values and that you are okay with having some nonzero values if that keeps the lengths of the selected values (i.e. the number of values selected from `arr1` and the number of values selected from `arr2` the same).

Here's the data I decided to play around with:

```py
a1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5]]

a2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [0, 1, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 3, 8, 0, 0, 2, 6, 0, 0, 0, 6, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0]]
```

Here's the code I use to find the indices of non-zero elements in `a1[1]` and `a2[1]` (i.e. the 2nd sublists):

```py
import numpy as np

# Get length of sublists
len_a1 = len(a1[0])
len_a2 = len(a2[0])

# Turn sublists into arrays
a1_arr = np.array(a1[1])
a2_arr = np.array(a2[1])

# Get indices of nonzero elements
a1_idx_nonzero = np.where(a1_arr != 0)[0]
a2_idx_nonzero = np.where(a2_arr != 0)[0]

# Get number of nonzero elements
length_a1_nonzero = len(a1_idx_nonzero)
length_a2_nonzero = len(a2_idx_nonzero)
```

And here's the code I used to select values from `a1` and `a2`. It selects all nonzero elements from both, as well as some extra zero values if the numbers of nonzero elements are not equal.

```py
# First case: number of nonzero elements in a1[1] and a2[1] are equal.
if length_a1_nonzero == length_a2_nonzero:
    good_a1 = [list(a1_idx_nonzero + 1), list(a1_arr[a1_idx_nonzero])]
    good_a2 = [list(a2_idx_nonzero + 1), list(a2_arr[a2_idx_nonzero])]

# 2nd case: a1 has more nonzero elements, so some zero elements are randomly selected from a2.
elif length_a1_nonzero > length_a2_nonzero:
    good_a1 = [list(a1_idx_nonzero + 1), list(a1_arr[a1_idx_nonzero])]

    a2_indices = np.arange(0, len_a2, 1)
    a2_indices_0 = np.delete(a2_indices, a2_idx_nonzero)

    # If number of nonzero elements in a1 is larger than the total number of elements in a2, choose all elements in a2.
    if length_a1_nonzero >= len_a2:
        good_a2 = [list(a2_idx_nonzero + 1), list(a2_arr[a2_idx_nonzero])]

    # Otherwise, randomly select some indices of zero elements from a2 and then select all desired values from a2.
    else:
        zeros_to_include = random.sample(list(a2_indices_0), length_a1_nonzero - length_a2_nonzero)
        a2_idx_nonzero = list(a2_idx_nonzero) + zeros_to_include
        a2_idx_nonzero.sort()

        good_a2 = [list(np.array(a2_idx_nonzero) + 1), list(a2_arr[a2_idx_nonzero])]

# 3rd case: same as 2nd case, but with a2 having more nonzero elements, so everything is just flipped.
else:
    good_a2 = [list(a2_idx_nonzero + 1), list(a2_arr[a2_idx_nonzero])]

    a1_indices = np.arange(0, len_a1, 1)
    a1_indices_0 = np.delete(a1_indices, a1_idx_nonzero)

    if length_a2_nonzero >= len_a1:
        good_a1 = [list(a1_idx_nonzero + 1), list(a1_arr[a1_idx_nonzero])]
    else:
        zeros_to_include = random.sample(list(a1_indices_0), length_a2_nonzero - length_a1_nonzero)
        a1_idx_nonzero = list(a1_idx_nonzero) + zeros_to_include
        a1_idx_nonzero.sort()

        good_a1 = [list(np.array(a1_idx_nonzero) + 1), list(a1_arr[a1_idx_nonzero])]
```

The selected values from `a1` and `a2` are stored in `good_a1` and `good_a2`:

```py
good_a1 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12], [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 5]]
good_a2 = [[2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 12, 13, 17, 18, 22], [1, 5, 6, 3, 8, 2, 6, 6, 4, 7]]
```

As you can see, `good_a1` has some zero values in the 2nd sublist because otherwise, `good_a1` would be too short compared to `good_a2`.

Let me know if you have any questions.